# How do you call remote servlet from android client?

Tags: android, servlets

I have developed android client which calls tomcat servlet which is on same PC. It runs fine.

I've used url

> http://10.0.2.2:8080/servletname

to call servlet and its working properly. Now i want to keep android client on one PC and Tomcat server on other. How should i proceed?

I have connected two laptops using LAN cable. I'm unable to configure all settings and permissions to call remote tomcat server.

Can anyone please tell me, how should i properly configure network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i want to keep android client on one PC and Tomcat server on other. How should i proceed?

Use the IP address of your Tomcat server.